# About cycles and the values in the range of a permutation function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $f = \{(x_1 y_1), (x_2 y_2), \ldots, (x_n y_n)\}$ be a permutation. A cycle of $f$ is given by $g = (1, f(1), f^2(1), f^3(1) \ldots)$. When counting permutations, we usually drop $1$ and count lists of the form $h = (y_1, y_2, \ldots,y_n).$

For example, let $(123)$ be a cycle which is $(231)$ if put in the form of $h$ above. Does it mean $g$ and $h$ are equal/same cycle?

Comment: Not clear on your notation.  When you denote $f$ do you mean that $(x_1y_1)$ is a transposition so that $f(x_1)=y_1$ and $f(y_1)=x_1$.  Or do you mean only that $f(x_1)=y_1$?

Comment: $f(x_1) = y_1$ only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g$ and $h$ are the same permutation.  You can see by writing both out in the form of $f$.

Comment: I wasn't sure. Thank you. Very nice.

Comment: Glad to help out.

Comment: I asked another question very much inspired by this one. Since you know what I am trying to understand, can you, please, check the edit to the question in the link and see where I tripped up: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373972/compose-1243-and-5/1373984?noredirect=1#comment2797017_1373984